# Why isnt this React variable working in my state object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

```
class Squares extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.color = 'blue';
    }

    state = {
        backgroundColor: this.color,
        width: "50px",
        height: "50px"
    };


    render () {

        return (
            <div>
                <div style={this.state}>Hello</div>
                <button>Add Square</button>
                <p>{this.state.backgroundColor}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }


}
```

this.color is outputting its value, but I cant assign it to this.state.backgroundColor. I eventually want to add a onClick event to the button and when I click it, i want to output a square with the color changed.

Comment: component `state` is meant to be used for pieces of data that are **subject to change** ... which means only the `background-color` of your square ... what r u having the whole `style` object in the component state?

Comment: Why don't you assign `blue` color directly to the state during initialisation and update the state using `setState` on button click?

Answer (score 4):

The primary issue here is actually just how JS works - any variables defined outside the constructor are initialized before the constructor.  For example:

```js
class Squares {
    constructor() {
        this.color = 'blue';
    }

    state = {
        backgroundColor: this.color,
        otherBackgroundColor: 'blue'
    };


    render () {
        console.log(this.state.backgroundColor)
        console.log(this.state.otherBackgroundColor)
    }
}

const s = new Squares();
s.render();
```

So if you need to access `this.color`, and you initialize it in the constructor, you need to initialize `this.state` in your constructor as well.

```js
class Squares {
    constructor() {
        this.color = 'blue';
        this.state = {
            backgroundColor: this.color,
        }
    }

  
    render () {
        console.log(this.state.backgroundColor)
    }
}

const s = new Squares();
s.render();
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.color = 'blue';` is not state managed.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        width: "50px",
        height: "50px"
    };
  }
```

this should work and instead of changing color update the value of backgroundColor

Comment: What if i want the background color of the square to be random when it is rendered.. wouldnt the backgroundColor value have to be a variable?

Comment: in that case you can initialise with a variable and then change the state directly or make the variable a state too.

Answer (score 1):

Some working code with button to add square and select to change background color of square.

Working codesandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-chaplygin-0m87u

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Squares extends Component {
  state = {
    showSquare: false
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      showSquare: true
    });
  };

  handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    this.setState({
      backgroundColor: target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { backgroundColor, showSquare } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ backgroundColor }} className={showSquare && "square"}>
          Hello
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Add Square</button>
        <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="red">red</option>
          <option value="purple">purple</option>
          <option value="green">green</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Squares;
```